# Can a wizard delay choosing spells for a spell book when leveling?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard

Imagine you have enough experience to gain two levels as a wizard.

Instead of choosing lower level spells to add to your spell book - can you delay adding spells to your spell book until your next level gain?

The reason we ask is because we notice that the tables list wizards as having x known spells - but it does not specify which level of spells they are. When we roll up a 5th level wizard - do we need to sit down and figure out the match imagining and then simulating how many spells of each level that person would have seen - or can we just look at the list of spells and pick out the x number of spells that wizard would know?

Comment: Think of it this way: you're not gaining two levels; you're gaining one level, and then immediately gaining another. No difference doing it this way to the "normal" way of levelling slower.

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate due to the difference in fluff about gaining spells as a wizard compared to a bard etc. A bard/sorcerer etc just gains access to more spells as they gain levels. A wizard has to do research and write them in their book. and if they have gained two levels at the same time  the spells they pick are down to that research and writing and  if it is deemed they have done this after levelling twice then that is quite different. I think there is something to be answered here.